# Does the lora E32-900T30D module (SX1276) have encryption?

Tags: lora, encryption, sx1276

I have an ebyte's E32-900T30D module (based on Semtech's sx1276) that I plan to use in a project, and I've got totally confused about presence (or absence) of built in encryption in it.

Each and every description of this module and of the IC states that it has an (AES128) encryption built in. Even its own datasheet says in the first paragraph that "The modules feature data encryption and compression." My problem is that now reading the datasheet carefully I can't find any trace of how exactly should I set up the keys, turn on encryption, etc. Looks like the module doesn't have encryption at all, despite the datasheet saying otherwise. Maybe someone could shed some light on this.

I hope it's the right place to ask this question.

Comment: please add a link to the device datasheet ... add it to the question, not in a comment

Comment: found this ...  https://how2electronics.com/interfacing-lora-sx1278-stm32-sender-receiver/

Comment: I dare say it depends on the firmware that’s loaded. Due to the low data rate overLora , even software crypto is adequate.